# Spring integration publishes a message in an outbound topic

Tags: jms, spring-integration

I have spring integration pipeline that should publish a message to an ActiveMQ topic. I'm trying to configure de spring xml file with the following configuration

```
<bean id="myTopic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
<constructor-arg value="topicMQ" />
</bean>


<si:channel id="myChannel" />
<jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut" channel="myChannel" destination="myTopic" />
```

but the message is not published to the topic. Do you have any idea how to configure spring integration to publish a message to a JMS Topic?
  I'll look forward for your answers.
Thank you,
  Florin

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
  <bean id="myTopic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
   <constructor-arg value="topicMQ" />
  </bean>

   <si:channel id="myChannel" />

  <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut"
   channel="myChannel" destination="myTopic"
   pub-sub-domain="true" delivery-persistent="true" time-to-live="600000" />
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: This didn't work for my Spring-Integration setup. Could you give more of yours? Maybe your connection factory or JMS template?